# AppEngine database model has has_key() method but is not iterable?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dictionary, cheetah

I am getting: *argument of type 'Lantern' is not iterable* in one of the template engine files (Cheetah). As you can guess the *obj* is a Lantern (see below).

**NameWrapper.py:**

```
if hasattr(obj, 'has_key') and key in obj:
```

This is a simplified version of my models. Nothing fancy, no additional methods just attribute declarations.

**models.py:**

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Product(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class Lantern(Product):
    height = db.IntegerProperty()
```

1. How can I solve this issue?
2. Is it correct, that AppEngine models have a function *has_key* but are not *iterable*?

**Solution(edit):**

I have replaced the line.

```
if hasattr(obj, 'has_key') and isinstance(obj, collections.Iterable) and key in obj:
```

Comment: `has_key` does not make an object iterable. It needs to support `__iter__`

Comment: @AnthonyKong: *or* be sequences (have a length and support indexing).

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NameMapper` implementation makes the erroneous assumption that having a `has_key()` method makes the `Model` class a mapping and tries to test for key membership.

This is a bug in the Cheetah `NameMapper` implementation and should be reported to the project. You could try to disable the `NameMapper` functionality, the documentation suggests [it is optional](http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/docs/users_guide_html/users_guide.html#SECTION000650000000000000000) and can be switched of with the `useNameMapper` compiler setting. I'm not familiar with the syntax, but try to avoid relying on the functionality in your templates.

If you are not averse to editing the Cheetah code, you could replace the tests with:

```
from collections import Mapping

if isinstance(obj, Mapping) and key in obj:
```

which uses the correct [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) to detect a mapping object.

`Model` objects are *not mappings*. The `Model.has_key()` function does not test for the presence of a mapping key, it is a method that tests if the object has a *datastore key*.

The documentation string on the method is:

```
def has_key(self):
    """Determine if this model instance has a complete key.

    When not using a fully self-assigned Key, ids are not assigned until the
    data is saved to the Datastore, but instances with a key name always have
    a full key.

    Returns:
      True if the object has been persisted to the datastore or has a key
      or has a key_name, otherwise False.
    """
```

Note that the above method does not take an argument, apart from the automatically-bound `self`.

`Model.has_key()` appears to be a convenience method that Google didn't include in the [*Model Class* documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass); it'll return `False` when the [`Model.key()` method](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_key)  would throw the `NotSavedError` exception instead.

In any case, `Model` objects are not sequences; they have no `__iter__` method, nor do they have a length or support indexing. As such they are not iterable. Having an `has_key()` method does not imply that they should be.

Answer (score 1):

The [release of Cheetah3 today](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Cheetah3) (3.0.0) includes the [bugfix for NameMapper.py functions](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/issues/3).